# Prove that for every integer $n$, $30 \mid n$ iff $5 \mid n$ and $6 \mid n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I don't really understand where to start with this proof. Its seams like modular arithmetic is needed? But I haven't covered that yet. Any assistance is helpful.

Answer (score 5):

If $5\mid n$ and $6\mid n$, then there exists integers $x$ and $y$ such that $n=5x=6y$. Then $5 \mid 6y$, so we get by Euclid's lemma that $5\mid y$ and hence $y=5z$ for some integer $z$. Therefore
$$ n = 6y = 6(5z) = 30z, $$
which proves $30\mid n$.

I'll leave the converse to you.

Answer (score 2):

$n = 6j\,$ so $\,5\mid 6j\,\Rightarrow\, 5\mid 6j\!-\!5j = j\,$ so $\,j=5k\,$  $\,\Rightarrow\,n=6j = 6(5k) = 30k$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general result.

If $a,b$ are relatively prime and $a\mid n$ and $b\mid n$ then $ab\mid n$.

Proof: Suppose $a,b$ are relatively prime and $a\mid n$ and $b\mid n$. Then choose integers $x,y$ such that $$ax+by=1.$$

Then $$a(nx)+b(ny)=n.(*)$$

Since and $a\mid n$ and $b\mid n$ choose integers $p,q$ such that $n=pa$ and $n=qb$. Then by $(*)$ we have $$n=a(qbx)+b(pay)=ab(qx+py).$$ Since $qx+py$ is an integer we have $ab\mid n$.